# how to capture and save HD images in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

ImageView imgFavorite;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    // set listener on image view
    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // open cam
          open();
       }
    });
 }
 public void open(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //we will use this function startActivityForResult() to launch this activity and wait for its result.
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
     imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
 }
```

this is my code which using existing camera application to capture images.. but it doesn't work on some android devices.. it doesn't save capture image in gallery .. how can i resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Use This Permission also :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Use This:

```
   ImageView drawingVIew = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);//let this be your image view
          //your other code
      drawingVIew.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawingVIew.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
                if (imgSaved != null) {
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                } else {
                    Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Oops! Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    unsavedToast.show();
                }
                drawingVIew.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Comment: actually only HD images are not showing in gallery ..is there any way to compress hd images ??

Answer (score 0):

yes you can compress the file. it depend the percentage you used. You should aplly the best number for the result you want. Like I am using the 100 in the following code

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yourImage);
        //here change the value from 100 to your best result of compressing
            the photo before saving . and this will also update the gallery
        newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

        fos.close();
        //refreshing gallery
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(yourImage));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pic not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```